# Users cannot read enterprise keywords

Tags: permissions, managed-metadata, managed-metadata-service, keyword, keyword-set

we have a site collection (SP 2010) in which one list has a "enterprise keywords" column (managed metadata service).

Well, the situation is that an user with administration permissions can read and write in the "enterprise keywords" column. But an **user without administration permissions can write but cannot read in the "enterprise keywords" column**.

It's ilogical but, an user with administration permissions can see the keywords that an user without administration permissions have written, but an user without administration permissions cannot see any keyword.

I have checked when an user without administration permissions write a keyword in the "enterprise keywords" column, the keyword is added in the term store in the right way.

I have assign full controll permissions to all authenticated users in the managed metadata service.

Summarize:

- In the same list, an user with administration permissions can see the value of the "enterprise keywords" column, but an user without administration permissions cannot read the value of that column.
- The ilogical point is that an user without administration permissions can add new keywords to the term store and to the list (I have checked this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a hidden taxonomy list at site collection level which is populated with terms as they are used.  The default is for all users to have read access on this list.  However, if you start with something like a blank site template and then retro fit MMD then it seems this permission does not always get applied.

Navigate to the hidden list at /lists/TaxonomyHiddenList and check the permissions.  If necessary grant read to All Authenticated Users.